# Fabric Crashlytics is shutdown but my app doesn't migrate to Firebase Crashlytic

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have an app on Google Play Store using Fabric Crashlytics and
Fabric SDK is not currently accepted and will continue to report your application problem until November 15, 2020. On this date, the Fabric SDK and old versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDK will stop sending crashes for your app.(https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)

I do not want to upgrade to Firebase because I do not use this function and keep current app version available on Google Play Store.

If so, does my application have a problem when Fabric shuts down all services, does it crash due to a failure to connect to the Fabric server?

Comment: You must migrate to Firebase crashlytics.  After Fabric shutting down there is no more support available

Comment: I mean, if I don't update Firebase Crashlytics, will the application still work after Fabric stops the service? Because I don't need Crashlytics anymore.
Do I have to remove the Crashlytics code?

Answer (score 4):

After November 15th, any apps still using the Fabric SDK will stop reporting crashes/non fatals. Any apps still using the Fabric SDK will continue to work, the Fabric SDK will just fail silently in the background, and not report any crash data.

Comment: I'm glad this is the answer. Is there a link to Google officially stating that?

Comment: Will it affect the app to be crashed in iOS or Android?